# How to scan for visible Airdrop devices via Applecript?

Tags: applescript, automator, automation, airdrop

I'm trying to figure out a way to scan for nearby airdrop devices and display a list of them but I've had trouble finding relevant examples or documentation. Can anyone point me in the right direction?